# How to change filter and style of vector layer after initialized?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to change filter and style like this

> -user enter search condition ==> filter condition change
>
> -user enter color of feature ==> style color of feature change

i know how to add filter and style for vector layers when initialization this vector, but
i dont know how to change style after that.

Answer (score 1):

One method to change color dynamically would be

```
YOUR_VECTOR_FEATURE.style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({fillColor: YOUR_FILL_COLOR}, 
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
```

I believe this overrides all other styling with defaults (you can just reassign it in the constructor though).

I'm not sure what kind of layer you are trying to filter but you can usually just do it with

```
YOUR_LAYER.filter = // filter goes here
YOUR_LAYER.refresh();
```

Comment: function changeFilter() {
        var queryFilter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.GREATER_THAN,
            property: "code_2004",
            value: "100" // something that does not exist in your dataset
        });
        wfs.style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({ fillColor: "#009900" },
        OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
        wfs.filter = queryFilter;
        wfs.redraw(); } filter not work but browser have not error